# $\max\frac{\Vert Ax \Vert _1}{\Vert x \Vert _2}$ for $x\neq 0$ and $L_{2,1}$ or $L_{1,2}$ norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Let $A$ be a $m \times n$ Matrix.

Consider the problem of $\max_{x\neq 0}\frac{\Vert Ax \Vert _1}{\Vert x \Vert 
 _2}$. From [wiki matrix norm page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#.22Entrywise.22_matrix_norms), it seems equal to $\Vert A \Vert _{2,1}$,
and on the same page
$$ \Vert A \Vert _{2,1} = \sum_{j=1}^n \Vert a_j \Vert _2 = \sum_{j=1}^n \left(\sum_{i=1}^{m} \vert a_{ij} \vert ^2\right)^\frac{1}{2}.$$

Is this correct? For two dimensional identity matrix $A = I_2$, I think the maximum is achieved at point $(\cos \frac{\pi}{4}, \sin \frac{\pi}{4})$, which is $\sqrt 2$. But $ \Vert I_2 \Vert _{2,1} = 2$. How can the value $2$ be reached? Is there any typos in the wiki definition on $L_{2,1}$? Maybe it is  $L_{1,2}$ for this problem? I think the answer is

$$ \max\frac{\Vert Ax \Vert _1}{\Vert x \Vert _2} = \Vert A \Vert _{1,2} = \Vert \vert a_j \vert_1\Vert_2  = \left(\sum_{j=1}^n \left(\sum_{i=1}^{m} \vert a_{ij} \vert\right)^2\right)^\frac{1}{2}$$, which seems correct for $A$ is diagonal matrix?

Also, what is the value of $x$ when the maximum is achieved?

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is correct. The Wikipedia article probably took the two sections from different sources and the notation is incoherent.

Note that none of the two alternatives that you mention can be the formula for your norm: with the example you give, 
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix} 1&1\\-1&1\end{bmatrix},
$$
it is easy to see that 
$$
 \sum_{j=1}^n \left(\sum_{i=1}^{m} \vert a_{ij} \vert ^2\right)^\frac{1}{2}
=\left(\sum_{j=1}^n \left(\sum_{i=1}^{m} \vert a_{ij} \vert\right)^2\right)^\frac{1}{2}=2\sqrt2,
$$
while
$$
\max\left\{\frac{\|Ax\|_1}{\|x\|_2}:\ x\ne 0\right\}=2. 
$$

Comment: thanks. Considering $A =  [1,1; -1,1]$, $x = (1,0)$ and $y = (2,2)$,  $|Ax|/||x|| > |Ay|/||y||$?

Comment: I have edited the answer. Now I'm not sure if there is an explicit formula for your norm.